# How can I convert 1v-1.3v at 5a-6a from two solar cells in series and supply 5v out?

Tags: pcb-design, components, solar-cell

Each cell is supplying 0.5v-0.65v and about 5A and I intend on using two of them in series for 1v-1.3v and need 5v out.

What ic(s) would be the best fit for this application?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.